# Redirect to a different page without changing url in browser

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I would be grateful for some assistance to achieve this:

- If a user browses to: `www.example.com/user/login`
- I would like the url to access
  `www.example.com/app/system/core/user/UserLogin.php`
- without the initial url changing in the browser.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let's see what you've tried first..

Comment: I tried to use htaccess with the RewriteRule, but I can only do the reverse procedure, ie turn this: www.example.com/app/system/core/user/UserLogin.php into www.example.com/user/login

Comment: @Stefano ... then what if you revert that rule you tried? ...

Comment: Edited title and question to present a clearer format to increase the chance of an answer. Please consider adding the code that you have tried so far to help people better understand the problems you are having, and to demonstrate that you have made an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Answer (score -1):

You can use the include, in PHP is
for example

```
include("app/system/core/user/UserLogin.php");
```

and your route would still be `www.example.com/user/login`

but it would take the functionalities of the file that you are calling

hope it has been helpful

Comment: thank you, I'll try this way

Comment: I doubt that is what the OP is looking for... What logic should get executed when requesting `/user/login`? That assumes there already is some form of rewriting implemented, if I am not totally mistaken...